# nginx ingress controller tls termination passthrough

Tags: nginx, ssl, kubernetes, nginx-ingress

Just deployed my docker image to Azure AKS and created nginx ingress controller. My image has the SSL certificate and handles SSL itself. So, I need a passthrough route to my container.

When I navigate to *https://just-poc.live*  famous nginx 502 gateway displays as below;

Apparently, nginx couldn't find a route to send https traffic.

What should I do to make nginx controller to route the traffic to my **socket-poc** deployment?

[image]

**nginx ingress controller**

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx       
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:     
      - path: /(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: socket-poc
            port:
              number: 8081
```

**deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: socket-poc
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: socket-poc
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: socket-poc
    spec:      
      containers:
      - name: socket-poc
        image: myownacrrepo.azurecr.io/socket:8081
        env:
        - name: TOOLBAR_COLOR
          value: "green"                
        resources:
          requests:
            cpu: 100m
            memory: 128Mi
          limits:
            cpu: 300m
            memory: 512Mi
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8081
          
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: socket-poc
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 8081
  selector:
    app: socket-poc
```

`kubectl get services` displays below;

```
NAME                                               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                      AGE
aks-helloworld-one                                 ClusterIP      10.0.34.79    <none>          80/TCP                       57m
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.0.74.62    20.93.213.132   80:31262/TCP,443:30706/TCP   35m
nginx-ingress-ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.0.177.29   <none>          443/TCP                      35m
socket-poc                                         ClusterIP      10.0.64.248   <none>          8081/TCP                     69m
```

`kubectl describe ingress hello-world-ingress` displays like this;

```
Warning: extensions/v1beta1 Ingress is deprecated in v1.14+, unavailable in v1.22+; use networking.k8s.io/v1 Ingress
Name:             hello-world-ingress
Namespace:        ingress-basic
Address:          20.93.213.132
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<error: endpoints "default-http-backend" not found>)
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *
              /(.*)   socket-poc:8081 (10.244.1.18:8081)
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-passthrough: true
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: true
Events:
  Type    Reason  Age                From                      Message
  ----    ------  ----               ----                      -------
  Normal  Sync    19m (x4 over 35m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
  Normal  Sync    19m (x4 over 35m)  nginx-ingress-controller  Scheduled for sync
```

Comment: nginx controller pod produces these error logs;


`2021/07/21 04:53:44 [error] 278#278: *34343 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 10.244.1.1, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://10.244.1.18:8081/favicon.ico", host: "20.93.213.132", referrer: "http://20.93.213.132/"`

Comment: also this;

`10.244.1.1 - - [21/Jul/2021:04:53:44 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 502 552 "http://20.93.213.132/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.164 Safari/537.36" 417 0.003 [ingress-basic-socket-poc-8081] [] 10.244.1.18:8081, 10.244.1.18:8081, 10.244.1.18:8081 0, 0, 0 0.000, 0.000, 0.004 502, 502, 502 ec77c33f79d3e9381927765760d21fe6`

Answer (score 5):

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"`  annotaion was missing. 502 error is gone!